# add bootstrap button by javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a bootstrap button into a row dynamically. Below is my code. A button is added but it is not bootstrap style.

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "button";
element3.name = "add";
element3.value="Remove";
element3.class="btn btn-danger btn-xs";
cell4.appendChild(element3);
```

Can someone tell the right way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This would be because `element3.class` is not a valid property.

You should be using `element3.className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"` instead

Comment: Mark answer as correct if this solved your question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should refer `className` property instead of `class` property.

```js
function myFunc()
{
  var cell4 = document.getElementById('insertHere');
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "button";
element3.name = "add";
element3.value="Remove";
element3.className="btn btn-danger btn-xs";
cell4.appendChild(element3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="insertHere"> </div>
<input type="button" value="addButton" onclick="myFunc()" />
```